# Architecture for mobile video uploads

Tags: ios, node.js, heroku, amazon-s3, api-design

I have an mobile application (native iOS) and I want to provide the user the ability to upload videos and associate them to their account.

Some considerations:

1. I have a Node.js API running on Heroku that I use to maintain the DB.
2. Videos on will be stored on S3

I am looking for some suggestions on how to architect this. Here is my sequence of events I am thinking...

1. The app POSTs to the API to create the "event" and receives back an S3 path
2. The mobile app uploads the video to the S3 path it received in step 1 response.
3. Upon successful upload the mobile app makes a PUT to update the API that the upload was successful.

I am curious how others have approached this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your example will work fine.

You can probably get rid of the first POST request to the API and offload the responsibility of dealing with S3 to your client app.

The opposite can also work -- you can have the API deal with uploading, so that you upload your file to the API and then it will store it in S3. This could be beneficial in situations where you have multiple client apps on different platforms and you want to offload all that work to the API instead of each client having to implement it.